# Cloud Bigtable: CheckAndMutateRow : row filter is failing with errors even after using ExactValueFilter

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

My goal is to update the existing value only if there is any change with the column value. Even though I am using ExactValueFilter still it is considered as a regex and failing with `)` missing in my value. I actually don't need to check whether the value is a standard regular expression or not. I would want to update the existing value independent of the actual value with CheckAndMutateRow.

```
client = bigtable.Client()
instance = client.instance("instance-name")
table_id = "table-name"
table = instance.table(table_id)
row_key = "row_key_1"
col_name = "col_name1"
cell_val = "test(value.pdf"
col1_filter = row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter(col_name)
label1_filter = row_filters.ExactValueFilter(cell_val)
chain1 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(filters=[col1_filter, label1_filter])

row_obj = table.conditional_row(row_key, filter_=chain1)
row_obj.set_cell("test_family_1", col_name, cell_val, state=False)
row_obj.commit()
```

`Error: InvalidArgument: 400 Error in chained row filter #1 : Error in field 'value_regex_filter' : Invalid RE2 regular expression 'test(value.pdf': missing ): test(value.pdf`